# 2 @click events for 1 html element using vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I'd like to bind 2 mouse click events to a div field. One of them is a shift+click, the other is a regular click, eg.

```
<div @click.shift="aaa()" @click="bbb()">...</div>
```

The problem is when I shift+click on the div not only aaa() is executed, but bbb(), too.
I tried to use some modifiers, eg. @click.shift.stop or similar, but bbb() has been executed all the time I clicked on the div. How can I solve this without separating the 2 kind of click events in a single function, eg. ccc() that calls either aaa() or bbb()?

Comment: `bbb` could check if shift is pressed and exit early

Comment: and if you needed to know how: `@click="bbb($event)"` `function bbb(event) { if (!event.shiftKey) return; /*...*/`

Comment: or `@click="bbb"` then as above - except it's `if (event.shifKey) return` - even in the above

Comment: "stopPropagation()" method could be used inside the @click.shift event handler

Comment: @AfzalK. what if `click` handler gets called before `click.shift`?

Comment: @JaromandaX hmm it didn't pass my mind, then we can use event modifiers .self or .prevent to prevent the event from propagating further, like @click.self.prevent="aaa()" @click.shift.self="bbb()

Comment: I dunno @AfzalK. did you try? I didn't :p

Comment: Unfortunately @click.self.prevent="aaa()" @click.shift.self="bbb() doesn't work, aaa() is not called when I simply click on it.

Comment: at least you have a solution though @ZsoltiVagyok

Comment: The event.shiftKey check inside bbb() works, but it's not nice. I'd prefer the vue.js way to solve this problem - if possible.

Comment: then, write code *in vue* that checks the shiftKey status  :p perhaps the boffins who wrote vuejs didn't think of this

Comment: well it was working when i was playing around sometimes ago, now i tested it and it calls both with shift, but now its fixed with some extra code

Comment: but @DiegoD's solution is working perfectly

Comment: @AfzalK. except for the inverted condition check of course - the guard should check if shift IS pressed - note, the `return` if the condition is true

Comment: Also, if you'd want to do it the "viewjs way" do know that the .shift modifier simply adds a guard that simply checks shiftKey. Which is exactly what everyone suggests you do: https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/b8fc18c0b23be9a77b05dc41ed452a87a0becf82/packages/runtime-dom/src/directives/vOn.ts#L22

Comment: Actually, digging the source made me find your expected solution, see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "exact" modifier.

```
<div @click.shift="aaa()" @click.exact="bbb()">...</div>
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#exact-modifier

> The `.exact` modifier allows control of the exact combination of system modifiers needed to trigger an event.

So this click event will trigger only if NO modifier were used, excluding it from executing when the @click.shift is triggered. Do note that this will also prevent alt+click, ctrl+click etc.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I overlooked this in the vue.js docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like so, add a single click handler which will dispatch the event accordingly.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    aaa() {
      console.log('aaa() executed!');
    },
    bbb(event) {
      if (!event.shiftKey) {
        console.log('bbb() executed!');
      }
    }
    ccc(event){
      if (event.shiftKey) {
        this.aaa(event);
      }else{
        this.bbb(event);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
      div {

        background-color: green;
        padding: 20px;

      }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <div @click="ccc($event)">Click me!</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works for sure, however the problem description says "How can I solve this without separating the 2 kind of click events in a single function, eg. ccc() that calls either aaa() or bbb()?"

So I'd prefer a vue native solution. Anyway, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    aaa() {
      console.log('aaa() executed!');
    },
    bbb(event) {
      if (!event.shiftKey) {
        console.log('bbb() executed!');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
      div {

        background-color: green;
        padding: 20px;

      }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <div @click.shift="aaa()" @click="bbb($event)">Click me!</div>
    </div>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: It does, thank you. Unless something more vue-like solution comes, this would be my choice. Though, I'd still like to solve this using vue.js's capabilities only.

Comment: @ZsoltiVagyok we can use '@click.once', but it executes one time